# Is it ok to spend a spurious mov eax, esi?

Tags: assembly

I'm writing a JIT compiler in a high level language and it happens that sometimes there are two cases. In the first case the receiving object is in `eax`, in the other it is in `esi`. Therefore, several routines have two versions, one based on `eax` and one in `esi`. Except for this, the two versions are semantically identical. Therefore I have two options:

1. Conditionally generate one routine or the other, or
2. Conditionally `mov eax, esi` and only generate the `eax`-based routine

Provided there won't be any side-effects, option 2 is better for the high level code because it simplifies the (native) code generation function. However, the native code will execute the additional `mov eax, esi` instead of using `esi` as the base addressing register.

**The question:** Which option is better?

Should I try to save a couple of CPU cycles and avoid the additional `mov`, or should I choose to simplify the high level code because the difference in performance will be negligible?

---

EXAMPLE

Note: `imm8` is just a placeholder for appropriate byte constants

**EAX-based routine:**

```
    test byte ptr [eax + imm8], imm8   ; EAX
    jz @1
    mov eax, [eax + imm8]              ; EAX
    jmp @2
@1:
    mov al, [eax + imm8]               ; EAX
    and eax, 255
@2:
    sal eax
    inc eax
```

**ESI-based routine (option 1):**

```
    test byte ptr [esi + imm8], imm8   ; ESI
    jz @1
    mov eax, [esi + imm8]              ; ESI
    jmp @2
@1:
    mov al, [esi + imm8]               ; ESI
    and eax, 255
@2:
    sal eax
    inc eax
```

**ESI-based routine (option 2):**

```
    mov eax, esi                        ; not present in option 1 
    test byte ptr [eax + imm8], imm8    ; EAX-based from now on
    jz @1
    mov eax, [eax + imm8]
    jmp @2
@1:
    mov al, [eax + imm8]
    and eax, 255
@2:
    sal eax
    inc eax
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take the option that simplifies the code.   Once your product is complete, if you find that the extra move is a significant performance problem, you can revisit the decision.   The difference will be that you have profiler data that will help you make that decision.

+1 for you, just for tackling a JTI.
You will learn a lot doing it.

Comment: It will be difficult to find a profiler that accurately reflects the cost of a one-instruction preamble on many functions. I don't think this answer is helpful.